# Python module loads in Jupyter but not in .py

Tags: python, module, python-imaging-library

I've run into an issue i don't know how to deal with.  I've written a Python script in Jupyter notebook.  The script works properly in Jupyter, but I need to call the script from a commandline, so I've converted it to a .py file using nbconvert.  When I run the script by explicitly calling python and the script with full paths, I get an error that a module couldn't be loaded properly.  It obviously didn't have any problem inside Jupyter, so I don't know what the problem with the module could be.  I saw another post that suggested updating all your modules, but that didn't change the behavior.  It has a problem with the PIL module.
Any help would be appreciated.  I only have one flavor of Python installed and I'm explicitly referencing the python.exe file in Anaconda folder.
Thanks for any help.
Vince
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdZkt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  Python couldn't find the module file because it was locked.  I had the script open in Jupyter.  Not sure why it was bothered by this module and not the others I was importing, but that was the problem here.